# How to embed a node on homepage in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

How can I embed a node on the front page in Drupal 6. The node basically has the image upload field along with title and description. I want it to some how appear on the homepage alongwith a "views" which shows the uploaded images at the bottom.

What I want is to give the users an ability to create content which is right now available at .../node/photo/add. I want to somehow show this box which lets one create content i.e. upload photo with title and description on the homepage.

It's basically just an attempt at creating something like imageshack as an experiment.

I am pretty n00b when it comes to drupal so please be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jukebox's solution works as a point-and-click method. If you want to do it with code, it's more like this:

- create a glue module [Handbook](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) | [Example Blog Post](http://geeksandgod.com/tutorials/computers/cms/drupal/creating-simple-drupal-module)
- turn it on in admin/build/modules
- create a menu item using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) that will become the page
- embed the node with [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_view)
- embed the view ([blog post](http://www.pixelclever.com/how-programmatically-insert-a-view-drupal-6))
- in admin/settings/site-information set your page to the

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Node Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module to, well, turn your node into a block. This means that you can go to the /admin/build/block page and place your node in a particular region.

After installing the module, edit the Content Type of the node you want to turn into a block. Under Workflow Settings, Available As Block, choose Enable.

Now you can go to /admin/build/block and you can see some new blocks. Just choose the one you want and place it in the region of your choice. You can also configure that block's visibility settings from there as well.

Comment: Thanks for this module but I don't think this is helping me in this case. What I want is to give the users an ability to create content which is right now available at .../node/photo/add.  I want to somehow show this box which lets one create content i.e. upload photo with title and description on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

If your planning on having a more complicated home page at any point in the future I'd highly recommend using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to do this.  It will allow you to arrange your front page with views and nodes in a grid method.

Comment: Thanks, Panels module is definitely something I will consider for something complex. I have even installed it and tried it but I think for my requirement right now it will be too much of an overkill. Thanks.